# Something is already running on port

Tags: node.js, mongodb, macos, express, npm

I am a fairly new developer and have come across a problem with ports. I am using mern stack and in my json file I have set the port to many different port numbers and it says something is running in all of them. I recently switched from google chrome to firefox and feel this could possibly be related. If I try to push yes on requesting a different port the page never loads. every time I run npm start the port is taken. Thank you

Comment: It would be great if you could show your configs. See [mcve]

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, it started working once I set a specific port. what are configs? and I will definitley check that out

Comment: Your *configurations*. Specifically, all you said is that you "set a port"... *where did you set it*?

Answer (score 0):

An easy workaround whenever you get a "port in use" message while developing node type of projects such as MERN type of stacks, the solution is to run a different port. So if you were on `localhost:3000`, change it to `localhost:3001`.

Answer (score 0):

Try stopping the running node process. Maybe a process using that port hasn't stopped.

Use Task manager (Windows) / Activity monitor (MacOs)